# Net.tcp service method and exception handling - WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, proxy

I have a WCF service with a service method, which is exposed using net.tcp with the help of a custom proxy. I was able to access my service method using my custom proxy without any trouble. 
However, the proxy fail to establish connection with service after adding exception handling in one of my service method.

The only difference between working and nonworking code is that, the non working code has exception handling in place for the a service method; where the working working version has no exception handling.

**What I did so far**

1. I did tried to change the security mode from None to Message
   eg:`binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;`
2. I restarted services such as `Net.Tcp Listner adaptor,Net.Tcp Port Sharing service`, and `Net.Pipe Listner Adaptor`.
3. I did execute the `ServiceModelReg.exe -r` command in admin mode.

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://mydom.com/mainrt/subrt")]
public interface IService
{
 [OperationContract]
 [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceException))]
 string CallToServiceMethod(object dataTransferObject);
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mydom.com/mainrt/subrt")]
public class ServiceException
 {
        [DataMember]
        public string ServiceMethodName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorInnerException { get; set; }

        public ServiceException()
        {
            ServiceMethodName = string.Empty;
            ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
            ErrorInnerException = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

**Implementation - Non working**

```
public string CallToServiceMethod(object dataTransferObject)
        {
            try
            {
               //code goes here               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<ServiceException>(new ServiceException()
                                                                    {
                                                                        ErrorInnerException = ex.InnerException.Message,
                                                                        ErrorMessage = ex.Message,
                                                                        ServiceMethodName = "CallToServiceMethod"
                                                                    });
}
```

**Implementation - Working**

```
public string CallToServiceMethod(object dataTransferObject)
            {
                try
                {
                   //code goes here               
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log exception details                
                }
          }
```

**Custom proxy and Trigger**

```
public void Use(UseServiceDelegate<T> codeBlock, string wcfEndPoint)
        {
            try
            {
                this.proxy = GetChannelFactory(wcfEndPoint).CreateChannel() as IClientChannel;
                if (this.proxy != null)
                {
                    this.proxy.Open(); // Here it fails when I have the exception handling. 
                    codeBlock((T)this.proxy);
                    this.proxy.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (CommunicationException commEx)
            {
                if (this.proxy != null)
                    this.proxy.Abort();

                throw commEx;
            }

        }

 ChannelFactory<T> GetChannelFactory(string wcfEndPoint)
        {
            ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = null;

            if (!channelPool.TryGetValue(wcfEndPoint, out channelFactory))
            {
                NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
                binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;
                binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 20000000;
                binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 20000000;

                binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None; // I did check it from None to Message/TCP but no luck
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = cpClientCredentialType.Windows;
                binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
                binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;


                EndpointIdentity epIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("email@email.come");
                EndpointAddress epAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(wcfEndPoint), epIdentity, new AddressHeaderCollection());

                channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, epAddress);
                channelPool.Add(wcfEndPoint, channelFactory);
            }

            return channelFactory;
        }
```

**Exception message** (when I call Open method on the proxy object)

```
{System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The message could not be dispatched because the 
 service at the endpoint address 'net.tcp://xxxxxxxxx/Service.svc' is unavailable for the protocol of the address.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.DecodeFramingFault(ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IConnection connection, Uri via, String contentType, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
```

Comment: enable WCF service tracing in both place at server and at client, that should give you idea about issue.

Comment: @Morbia,Tracing is enabled at server. But not sure how at client side since connection is established through custom proxy.

Comment: WCF Tracing at client side independent to the endpoint, just add tracing configuration in the client app.config and it should work.